# Java: why does FileReader method .read() needs a variable?

Tags: java, filereader

So, I have a text file that contains exactly "aaaa" and 2 codes:

```
import java.io.*;
public class ex7 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        File file = new File("C:\\a.txt");

        try {
            FileReader reader = new FileReader(file);
            int ch;
            while ((ch = reader.read()) != -1)
                System.out.print((char)ch);
            reader.close();
        }catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }
}
```

this output reads "aaaa", as it should.

```
import java.io.*;
public class ex7 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        File file = new File("C:\\a.txt");

        try {
            FileReader reader = new FileReader(file);
            while (reader.read() != -1)
                System.out.print((char)reader.read());
            reader.close();
        }catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }
}
```

Although I've only changed the existance of the int variable ch, this output reads "aa". Why does that happen? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Because you call read() once in `while (reader.read() != -1)` and ignore what it returns, and then call it a second time, thus reading the next character, in `System.out.print((char)reader.read());`.

Comment: Because each call to read() advances the reader.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`reader.read()` => Read character every time its called. So in the second case, it is called 4 times but only printed two times.

To better understand, replace the content of the file with `abab`, then you will see `bb` as output because alternate characters are skipped.